# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): props.prices is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The ICrypto -

```
interface ICrypto {
  readonly BTCUSD: number;
  readonly ETHUSD: number;
  readonly LTCUSD: number;
}
```

Here is the .tsx file -

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { backendAPIAxios } from '../../../utils/http';

import { ICrypto } from '../../../models/crypto';

import PricesView from './Prices.view';

interface Props {
  readonly prices: (value: ICrypto) => void;
}

const Prices: React.FC<Props> = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<Props>) => {

  const [ pricesState, setPricesState ] = useState<ICrypto | null>(null);

  const pricesChangeHandler = (value: ICrypto | null) => setPricesState(() => value);

  backendAPIAxios.get(`/prices`)
  .then(() => {
    props.prices(pricesState!);
  });

  return (
    <PricesView
      prices={pricesState}
      pricesChangeHandler={pricesChangeHandler}
    >{props.children}</PricesView>
  );
};

Prices.displayName = 'Prices';
Prices.defaultProps = {};

export default Prices;
```

Here is the view.tsx file -

```
interface Props {
  readonly prices: ICrypto | null;
  readonly pricesChangeHandler: (value: ICrypto | null) => void;
}

const PricesView: React.FC<Props> = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<Props>) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  
  return (
    <div>{props.prices?.BTCUSD}</div>
  );
};
```

New to react I don't get the problem, how can I solve the error?
....................................................................................................................................................

Comment: your view has a prop called `prices` which is not a function and a component `Prices` that has a function prop, where is the error occuring?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in a part of the code you have not shared.
You are calling `props.prices(pricesState)` and from the error, you can see that either you are not passing a function to that prop.